# Comparing to a string literal in a console application

Tags: c++, character-encoding

I have a simple native C++ console app.
I want to stay something like this:

```
Quit? (Y/N)
```

and be able to type in Y or N to tell the program what to do?
So far I have this code:

```
std::string whetherToQuit;
std::cout<<"Quit? (Y/N): ";
std::cin>>whetherToQuit;
if(whetherToQuit == "Y"){
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
else if (whetherToQuit == "N"){
        break;
}
```

MSVC++ gives me a warning and I think there should be a better way to do this.
If it matters I am using Windows.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't exit(), use return. exit() circumvents RAII.

Comment: VS2010 and W4 does not emit a warning on my machine.

Comment: No warning here either, VS2005.. Code looks fine to me, although I'd maybe use a char*, or else compare the string using string.compare(""). Oh, and also, probably want to test for lowercase as well..

Comment: @StevieG: Why skip good C++ strings for bad C char*?

Comment: Use char and also change it to lower case so both y and Y works.

Comment: @phresnel: I don't see much reason for creating an instance of a string class with all the overhead that goes with it to hold a single character. I'd use a string if the input was a string (i.e. more than 1 char) and/or it was going to be manipulated in some way by the code..

Comment: @StevieG: I reckon what you meant was `char`, not `char*` as you wrote.

Comment: @phresnel: oops, yes, didn't notice that, should be char

Comment: @Ólafur Waage: many unix programs assume strictly lowercase for defaults, and strictly uppercase for destructive decisions. E.g., some install script would ask `Delete previous settings (nY, default: n)?`. A good thing, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three points worth mentioning:

1. Why are you using string? Use char instead:

   char ans;
   if (ans == 'Y') {
   // op
   }
   else if (ans == 'N') {
   // op
   }
2. Why are you using "break" inside else if. **A break statement may only be used within a switch or loop.**
3. [ADDED] Use return instead of Exit. Exit circumvents RAII.

Final code should look like

```
char ans;
std::cout << "Quit? (Y/N): ";
std::cin >> ans;
if (ans == 'Y') {
    return 0;
}
else if (ans == 'N') {
    // No op;
}
```

Comment: No, as a commenter already mentioned, you shouldn't exit() in C++, as it circumvents RAII. `return` instead.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: I'll remove my downvote once you replace exit with return. But encouraging exit is really not good.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a `char` instead:

```
char ans;
std::cout << "Quit? (Y/N): ";
std::cin >> ans;
if (ans == 'Y') {
    return 0;
}
else if (ans == 'N') {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the warning message say?

You can do like this:

```
const std::string strYes = "Y";
const std::string strNo = "N";
```

and then compare with this constants.